# N + 1 error with view

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I think what is causing this N + 1 error is that since the view has to render the collection, each status update needs to make a query call in order to display it's variables relative to the other status updates.

This makes for a lot of queries. How could I make all these status updates available at once, and simply call the array, from within the status update class, to make these calculations instead of going to the database every time?

I might be missing something so any insight would be great! I've tried changing my query calls using include, and about 100 other things.

This is the error bullet is giving me:

```
user: Pablo
N+1 Query detected
  StatusUpdate => [:client]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:client]
N+1 Query method call stack
 /Users/Nick/Code/Rails/gj/app/models/status_update.rb:27:in `prev'
 /Users/Nick/Code/Rails/gj/app/models/status_update.rb:36:in `weight_change'
 /Users/Nick/Code/Rails/gj/app/models/client.rb:11:in `weight_change'
 /Users/Nick/Code/Rails/gj/app/views/status_updates/show.html.erb:39:in    `_app_views_status_updates_show_html_erb__176120213182464780_70358939483460'
```

status_updates.rb

```
 def prev
   prev = self.client.status_updates.where("created_at < ?", self.created_at)[-1]
   if prev == nil
     prev = self
   else
    prev 
   end
 end        

 def weight_change
   weight_change = prev.total_weight - total_weight
   cut weight_change
 end
```

client.rb

```
def weight_change(stat_present)
 if stat_present == false
   0
 elsif stat_present == true
   self.status_updates.reverse.first.weight_change
 end
end
```

StatusUpdatesController#show

```
  def show
    if status_updates?
      current_client.id).limit(7).reverse
      @status_updates = current_client.status_updates.limit(7).reverse
    end
    @status_update = current_client.status_updates.new
  end
```

show.html

```
  <% if @status_updates != nil %>
      <%= render(partial: "status_updates", collection: @status_updates) %>
  <% else %>
      <p style="text-align:center">No status updates yet.</p>
  <% end %>
```

_status_updates.html

```
<tr>
    <td class="left"><%= status_updates.entry_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %></td>
    <td class="left phase"><%= status_updates.phase %> <a href="#">+</a></td>
    <td><%= status_updates.total_weight %></td>
    <td><%= status_updates.weight_change %></td>
    <td><%= status_updates.lbm_weight %></td>
    <td><%= status_updates.lbm_change %></td>
    <td><%= status_updates.total_lbm_change %></td>
    <td><%= BigDecimal(status_updates.body_fat_pct * 100, 5)%>%</td>
    <td><%= status_updates.fat_change %></td>
    <td><%= status_updates.total_fat_change %></td>
    <td><%= link_to('&times;'.html_safe, status_updates, method: :delete) %></td>
</tr>
```

client.rb

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :trainer
   has_many :status_updates

   validates :firstname, :lastname, presence: true

   def weight_change(stat_present)
     if stat_present == false
       0
     elsif stat_present == true
       self.status_updates.reverse.first.weight_change
     end
   end

   def fat_change(stat_present)
     if stat_present == false
       0
     elsif stat_present == true
       self.status_updates.reverse.first.fat_change
     end
   end

   def lbm_change(stat_present)
     if stat_present == false
       0
     elsif stat_present == true
       self.status_updates.reverse.first.lbm_change
     end
   end

   def bfp_change(stat_present)
     if stat_present == false
       0
     elsif stat_present == true
       self.status_updates.reverse.first.bfp_change
     end
   end

   def total_weight_change(stat_present)
     if stat_present == false
       0
     elsif stat_present == true
       self.status_updates.reverse.first.total_weight_change
     end
   end

end
```

Comment: Why don't you simply save the weight_change to the `status_update` when you create it?

Comment: Show the content of _status_updates

Comment: Instead of using `some_array[-1]`, it would be better to use `some_array.last` if for nothing more than just clarity.

Comment: ok I edited the question to include both the partial and the model calls from the partial so you get a fuller understanding of what's going on.

Comment: @UriAgassi I get it. So instead of searching for this info with each call to the status updates I can just save the info to each status update as they are created so I'm only calling info from within each status update as that info relates to the others.

Comment: @UriAgassi  If you could write that as an answer I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that instead of computing `weight_change` each time you *read* a `status_update`, you should compute it when you *write* the `status_update` in its own column (`weight_change`).

This way reading a record is straight forward, and doesn't need any looping back to older records.